# Autocomplete not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

This site: http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ ajax autocomplete works fine in firefox and chrome, but the page from this repo: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete.git ajax autocomplete dropdown is not working.

I need help on which file should I add from this site http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ so the ajax dropdown autocomplete in page of this repo(https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete.git) will work in chrome.

I'm using GoogleChrome version: 24.0.1312.57 in windows.

Comment: have you tried reinstaling chrome.. It is a bug in most of the cases... Which is easily resolved by reinstalling chrome...

Comment: thanks to your response, Haven't yet tried re-installing but I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

I find a link on chrome site :

Chrome : You should have to activate autocomplete :

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en